# Docker : How to run a Bokeh server inside Docker container and expose the output

Tags: docker, server, bokeh

I have a Bokeh python code that imports data from excel file and projects my supplier locations on Google maps. The excel file is stored on my local host in the folder C:\Python where the Python code is picking it from.This code works fine with I open command prompt and use the command "Bokeh serve --show Gmaps_Bokeh.py".
However, when I build the docker file to do that same and map the port 5006 to 2000 I cannot see anything in my browser.

I have created a Docker folder on my host that contains Gmaps_Bokeh.py , Sid.xls and Dockerfile and in my Dockerfile I am copying all the contents in /Python directory of container.

## The docker terminal shows the following

```
$ docker run -p 5006:2000 sid
2019-11-03 20:38:43,329 Starting Bokeh server version 1.3.4 (running on 
Tornado 6.0.3)
2019-11-03 20:38:43,334 Bokeh app running at:    
http://localhost:5006/Gmaps_Bokeh
2019-11-03 20:38:43,334 Starting Bokeh server with process id: 1
```

## Dockerfile contents

```
 FROM python
 RUN pip install bokeh
 RUN pip install gmaps
 RUN pip install pandas
 RUN pip install xlrd
 WORKDIR /Python
 COPY . /Python
 EXPOSE 2000
 CMD ["bokeh", "serve","/Python/Gmaps_Bokeh.py"]
```

Comment: Did you check Bokeh [docker-tools](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/docker-tools)?

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around `docker run -p 2000:5006` ?

Comment: And shouldn't you use `--address 0.0.0.0` in your `bokeh serve` command?

Comment: Could you tell me if there is something wrong with my Docker file? I would appreciate any help as I cannot find any Docker command related to Bokeh. Every link talks about Bokeh / Flask and then Docker. I want to avoid Flask altogether.

Comment: Hard to say... You should post some more info like: what your `docker ps` or `docker inspect <your-docker-container-id>` returns? Did you try to run docker with `--name` and then enter the docker container (`docker exec -it <name> bash`) and see if you have communication with Bokeh server? Docker networking can be complicated, see also [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) for some info

Answer (score 0):

To get access to folder on host, you need to use docker volumes to map host's c:/python into some linux path. Also, you need to reconfigure your application to use that path (on container) and not c:/python (or any other direct host windows path).

Comment: Can I rather copy Sid.xls into container's /app folder and Bokeh running inside container can access this file?

Comment: Yes, this is also an option. To copy files between host and container (and vice versa) use `docker cp`command (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you have your ports messed up. Think of the host and container ports separately.

As seen in the console output once you run the container inside your container, you have bokeh which publishes on port 5006 (here localhost is from the point of view of the container). This is what you need to expose in your Dockerfile (thus it should be `EXPOSE 5006`). So far you're inside the container and don't know anything about port 2000.

If you want to expose your container port 5006 (where bokeh serves) to a host system port 2000, you would do this as in @Tony's comment using `-p 2000:5006` in your docker run command and look for it with `http://localhost:2000` in your browser.

One important clarification that should glue all this together: localhost when requested from the host system (where you run your browser) is different from localhost when requested from the container (where the bokeh console output comes from).